# Use of backslashes with variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell and found this function. I understand that with backslash
you can create lambda functions.

```
-- >(\x -> (fst x)* (snd x)) (2,3)
-- 6
```

What I don't understand is the use of backslashes here. Could someone explain me please.

```
 voltea::(a -> b -> c) -> b->a->c
 voltea = \f -> \x -> \y -> f y x
 main = print(voltea div 2 6)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember, this

```
f = \x -> <thing>
```

is the same as this

```
f x = <thing>
```

Given that, perhaps your expression will make more sense to you if I give the parenthesis

```
voltea = (\f -> (\x -> (\y -> f y x)))
```

is the same as

```
voltea f = (\x -> (\y -> f y x))
```

is the same as

```
voltea f x = \y -> f y x
```

is the same as

```
voltea f x y = f y x
```

Now, remember that in Haskell, functions are just regular objects that can be passed into other functions, and you should be able to understand what this last line does.

Answer (score 2):

All Haskell functions are curried. Procedure of applying function to it's parameters is right associative. It allows to rewrite `voltea` in following way:

```
voltea :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
voltea =
  \ f ->        -- `voltea` is a lambda taking one parameter `f`.
    (\ x ->     -- It returns another lambda which takes `x`.
      (\ y ->   -- That lambda return another lambda again which takes `y`.
        f y x)) -- And that last lambda applies `f` to `y` and `x`
```

So, it's the same as to write `voltea` in form:

```
voltea f x y = f y x
```